# Python 2.6 threading KeyError with Apache

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, macos

I'm running Apache, installed using macports on OS X, to serve a Django app.

I'm getting many lines in the Apache error_log like these:

```
[Wed Feb 23 11:35:42 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1606572256,) in <module 'threading' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

The server doesn't seem to be having noticeable problems while these errors are logged, but it does crash every so often requiring a manual restart - which may or may not be related to these error messages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[That bug is almost a year old. Update mod_wsgi.](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=197)